# How do I turn Keycloak old version 4.1.0 into 'Standalone server distribution'?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, keycloak, keycloak-services

I tried something (readme.md, blog etc).But I don't turn 'standalone server distribution'.
I can give an example. What I want to say:

The following is a 'standalone server distribution' files. This is ready for running.

Picture-1

[image]

I need to run old version keycloak (version 4.1.0). This package seem like this :

Picture-2

[image]

According to Picture-2, this packages don't ready for running.

How can I ready for running ? Like to Picture-1.

**I need your suggestions and suggestions. Can you help me?**

Greetings,

Answer (score 1):

That's the source code.
You have to build it by executing the following command from parent directory (you need Java JDK and Maven installed and configured):

```
mvn -Pdistribution -pl distribution/server-dist -am -Dmaven.test.skip clean install
```

Resulting release distribution will be in `./distribution/server-dist/target/keycloak-4.1.0.Final.zip` archive.

Compiling the sources is described here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/docs/building.md

You can download the latest release version 4.X from archive: https://www.keycloak.org/archive/downloads-4.8.3.html

Comment: Thanks for your advice.I'll try :)